# php foreach multilevel menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá amigos tudo bem ?

Estou com o seguinte problema eu tenho esse banco de dados preciso criar um menu com multilevel para o blog do site, criei um com o seguinte código:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display: block;">
        <?php
        $catsPassadas = array();
        foreach ($blog_categorias as $key => $blog_categoria) {
            $blog_categorias_filhasQ = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog_categoria WHERE id_pai = :id_pai ORDER BY nome ASC');
            $blog_categorias_filhasQ->bindValue(':id_pai', $blog_categoria['id_pai'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $blog_categorias_filhasQ->execute();
            $blog_categorias_filhas = $blog_categorias_filhasQ->fetchall();
            if($blog_categorias_filhas){
                print_r($blog_categorias_filhas);
                echo '<br><br><br>';
        ?>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?=$blog_categoria['nome']?>
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
                foreach ($blog_categorias_filhas as $keyf => $blog_categoria_filha) {
                    if (in_array($blog_categoria['id'], $catsPassadas)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $catsPassadas[] = $blog_categoria_filha['id'];
        ?>
                    <li><a href="#"><?=$blog_categoria_filha['nome']?></a></li>
        <?php
                }
        ?>
                </ul>
            </li>       
        <?php
            }else{
                if (in_array($blog_categoria['id'], $catsPassadas)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $catsPassadas[] = $blog_categoria['id'];
        ?>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><?=$blog_categoria['nome']?></a></li>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
```

mas não obtive sucesso, como posso estar solucionando esse problema?

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver, estava fazendo a consulta sql de forma errada comparando id_pai com id_pai onde deveria ser id_pai com id

```
$blog_categorias_filhasQ = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog_categoria WHERE id_pai = :id ORDER BY nome ASC');
            $blog_categorias_filhasQ->bindValue(':id', $blog_categoria['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $blog_categorias_filhasQ->execute();
```